# i have multiple radio button in same name as array and same value

Tags: php, html, arrays

i have multiple radio button  in same name as array and same value for all.

```
   <input type="radio" name="radio_name[]" id="radi_name" value="1" checked>
   <label for="radio1">Set as Default</label>
   <input type="radio" name="radio_name[]" id="radi_name" value="1"  >
   <label for="radio1">Set as Default</label>
   <input type="radio" name="radio_name[]" id="radi_name" value="1"  >
   <label for="radio1">Set as Default</label>
   <input type="radio" name="radio_name[]" id="radi_name" value="1" >
   <label for="radio1">Set as Default</label>
```

in php i used like this

```
    $a[]=$_post['radio_name'];
    prinr_r($a);
```

im getting result like this :

```
Array ( [0] => 1 )
```

if i uncheck the button set as zero i want result to be like this

```
Array ( [0] => 1,[1] => 0,[2] => 0,[3] => 0 )
```

Please check this images [i have form like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w08Dp.png)

Comment: yes but still  i'm not getting solution i'm strucking there

Comment: Radio buttons are not used for multiple select options. Use checkboxes or multiple select instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that radio buttons don't get sent to the server if none of the values is selected. In your html you really have 4 different radio button groups so only the ones that have a selected value, get sent.

If you want 4 groups where a value always gets sent for each group, you should do something like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio_name[1]" value="1" id="radio1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="radio_name[1]" value="0">
<label for="radio1">Set as Default</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio_name[2]" value="1" id="radio2">
<input type="radio" name="radio_name[2]" value="0" checked>
<label for="radio2">Set as Default</label>
// etc.
```

This way you will have independent radio button groups and you will get the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use only `[]` instead of array keys also use `checkbox` instead of `radio` . So use following code it will work for you.

```
         <input type="checkbox" name="radio_name[]" id="radi_name1" value="1" checked>
         <label for="radio1">Set as Default</label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="radio_name[]" id="radi_name2" value="1"  >
         <label for="radio1">Set as Default</label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="radio_name[]" id="radi_name3" value="1"  >
         <label for="radio1">Set as Default</label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="radio_name[]" id="radi_name4" value="1" >
         <label for="radio1">Set as Default</label>
```

Comment: i have tried that aslo but i wont worked for me

Comment: That is really the same as the OP's code.

Comment: Till  i'm not getting solution

Comment: invalid html due to duplicate ID attributes. Given also that the value is the same for each then effectively there is a single element not four.

Comment: @RamRaider , I just correct the code for name and required one only. And user is not using id so I skipped that. Anyway thank you for point out this let me correct this code even.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use checkbox instead of radio. Radio only allowed 1 value being posted, and remove the array key like dipmala suggested.

Comment: Hey @Eng Cy yes you are true, and really I skip that its radio button . Thank you for correcting.

Comment: but all in one group of button need to check either one if i use checkbox they can check multiple dude

Comment: What you need is the checked result, why need to get all un-checked radio?

Comment: please guys check image above i have form like that